# ASM AdviceAdapter onMethodEnter - Print all arguements

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm looking use ASM to print values of all parameters passed into a method.  I've found some examples, but I can't make sense of it.  To be honest, I probably haven't done my "homework" in the sense that I haven't studied ASM as much as I need to in order to build this.  But if anyone's willing to help me out that would be great.

Just for an example, say the method returns a void and takes a single integer as a parameter.

(and I've seen the example at https://gist.github.com/VijayKrishna/1ca807c952187a7d8c4d)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.  Here we go.

Here's method injector class.  It reads in a class file (Print.class) and adds the instruction to print the int whenever PrintInt method gets called

```
package asm;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Attribute;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class PrintInjector extends ClassVisitor {

    public PrintInjector(int api, ClassVisitor mv) {
        super(api, mv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access,  name,  desc,  signature,  exceptions);
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s", name, desc, signature));
        if(name.equals("PrintInt"))
                mv = new PrintSingleIntParameter(Opcodes.ASM5, mv, access, name, desc);
        return mv;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream(new File("bin\\Print.class")));
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        PrintInjector pi = new PrintInjector(Opcodes.ASM5, cw);

        cr.accept(pi,  0);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("Print.class"));
        fos.write(cw.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }

    class PrintSingleIntParameter extends AdviceAdapter {

        protected PrintSingleIntParameter(int api, MethodVisitor mv, int access,
                String name, String desc) {
            super(api, mv, access, name, desc);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMethodEnter() {
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 0); //1 instead of 0 if PrintInt wasn't static
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(I)V", false);
        }       
    }
}
```

Here's my Print.class

```
public class Print {
    public static int PrintInt(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = PrintInt(10);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

The output

```
10
a:10
Done
```

You're going to need to adjust the code in onMethodEnter to suit whatever needs you have.  I'm realizing now the code I have doesn't keep the bytecode clean (as in it breaks when I use it in other programs that use registers after this code is ran).

Comment: That's basically correct, but in general you need to pass `ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES`, not `0`, to the call  `cr.accept(pi,  ___);`. And you don't need the label.